# Can't get my cURL Cron Job to initiate a PHP script

Tags: php, curl, cron

I'm new to writing Cron Jobs and I can't seem to initiate my PHP script. My current Cron looks like the following:

```
/usr/local/bin/curl http://{my-url}/ajax.php?cron=execute
```

I figured I could use a string query and cURL to execute the specific function in my ajax.php file, as such:

```
if(isset($_GET['cron']) && $_GET['cron']=='execute'){
   populate_new_csv();
}
```

The populate_new_csv() function is currently executed with an AJAX function on the front-end to pull data from an API and generate a .CSV file populated with that data. I'm trying to make this work with a cron job as well but It's a little out my knowledge so any help would be incredibly appreciated.

Comment: If you are running the cron locally, why don't you use execution parameters, like through the use of `getopt()`?

Comment: Get it to work command line first before putting it as a CRON. Does `/usr/local/bin/curl http://{my-url}/ajax.php?cron=execute` run?

Comment: Note that you need to put the entire url in single quotes when you run this on the cli.

Comment: @user3783243 I'm new to openSSH but I've just attempted a few variations of the cron in crontab but none have generated new .csv files. Here are two examples that I've used:

`* * * * * /usr/local/bin/curl 'http://{my_url}/ajax.php?cron=execute'`

`* * * * * curl -s 'https://{my_url}/ajax.php?cron=execute'`

Comment: First get it to run command line, then get CRON to run.

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks to @user3783243 and @Roadowl** I was able to finally use CRON to execute a php function/script with a query string. Just wanted to post up how I found my solution (and what it was).

I started out by accessing my website through openSSH and initiating crontab. I ended each CRON with `>> /home/{my_user}/public_html/cronerror.txt` so I could log any errors.

I wrote down all examples of CRON jobs I wanted to test in a txt and tested them one by one. Here are some examples:

- `* * * * * /usr/local/bin/curl "http://{my_url}/ajax.php?cron=execute" >> /home/{my_user}/public_html/cronerror.txt`
- `* * * * * curl -s http://{my_url}/ajax.php?cron=execute  >> /home/{my_user}/public_html/cronerror.txt`
- `* * * * * curl -s "http://{my_url}/ajax.php?cron=execute" >> /home/{my_user}/public_html/cronerror.txt`
- `* * * * * wget "http://{my_url}/ajax.php?cron=execute" >> /home/{my_user}/public_html/cronerror.txt`

The first three produced 301 errors in the cronerror.txt file, however the last example using wget instead of curl worked correctly. As pointed out by @Roadowl, the entire URL has to be contained by quotes.